Penzai pz.ts.register_as_default() using 64GB of GPU
I've attached my jupyter notebook to a slurm node with an 80GB A100. When I import packages and run other commands, and then run nvidia-smi, I get
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off |   00000000:E1:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P0             53W /  300W |       0MiB /  81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

which I think is okay. But after I run pz.ts.register_as_default() and the call completes, I get
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off |   00000000:E1:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P0             73W /  300W |   61219MiB /  81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   1106583      C   .../MYFILEPATH                              61210MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

The memory use is confirmed since the program crashes when I attempt to load up a 21 GB model later. Looking at the documentation I don't see why this should be the case. Anyone have ideas?
